# POST запрос, requests перестал работать код

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests

Не так давно перестали работать мои запросы, написанные для одного проекта.
Данные никак не менялись, через браузер плагин rested получаю 200, через pycharm 401. В чем может быть причина, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Пример кода:

```
print('Получение токена')
r = requests.post('https://link', data={'grant_type': 'password', 'client_id': '3', 'client_secret': 'G3YZfTHKLT5', 'username': 'test@dev.ru', 'password': 'G3YZfT'}, verify=False)
print(r)
print("\n------- status/headers/encoding ---------")
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print("\n----------------- text ------------------")
print(r.text)
print("\n----------------- json ------------------")
print(pprint.pprint(r.json()))
print("\n---------------- headers ----------------")
for key, value in r.headers.items():
    print(key, ' => ', value)

# get
print('Пользователи - получение')
url = 'https://link'
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token'
}
r2 = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
#response.raise_for_status()
print(r2.status_code)
print(r2.json())
```

Comment: Там все правильно передается https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401?

Comment: Да, раньше был ответ 200 через pycharm, сейчас 401. Через плагин браузера получаю также 200 ответ со старыми данными.

Comment: Мб заголовок User-Agent ему не нравится... А первый запрос точно не json? `r = requests.post('https://link', json={...`?

Comment: Причина поломки - включение авторизации на сервере. Добавила авторизацию в ссылку, все заработало. Может, это кому-то поможет.

Comment: Оформите тогда это как собственный ответ :) Странно, что через плагин проблемы не было